# paste character vector as a comma separated, unquoted list in R

Tags: r

I have a character vector that looks like this

```
vector <- c('a','b','c','d','e')
```

I have an object in a for-loop that takes input as:

```
out[a,] <- c(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Where `a-e` are variables with values (for instance, `a=0.7`). I would like to feed the `out` object some transfomred version of ther `vector` object. I've tried

```
paste(noquote(vector),collapse=',')
```

However, this just returns

```
"a,b,c,d,e"
```

Which is still not useful.

Comment: If this is for printing `cat(paste(noquote(vector),collapse=','), '\n')`

Comment: @akrun its for inputting variables with these same names into a matrix of output data from a simulation run. How can I edit the question to make this clear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mget` to put objects into a named list:

```
# data
a <- 1; b <- 2; c <- 3; d <- 4; e <- 5

mget(letters[1:5])

$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3

$d
[1] 4

$e
[1] 5
```

or wrap it `mget` in `unlist` to get a named vector:

```
unlist(mget(letters[1:5]))
a b c d e 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 9):

Reverse the order of the function calls:

```
noquote(paste(vector, collapse = ','))
```

This will print `[1] a,b,c,d,e`. If you don't like the `[1]` use

```
cat(paste(vector, collapse = ','))
```

which prints

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

Comment: thanks- I need these to be evaluated, as they reference stored variables within the loop. For instance, at this step in the loop `a=0.7, b=0.01`, etc. How can I have the printed list be evaluated?

Comment: @colin I think you need to be more explicit about what you want printed by editing relevant info into your question or, if it's too much of a change, into a new question. Anyways, I use `cat(x, "\n")` (where `x` is a string) inside a loop all the time myself.

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic question and ate my head almost with a tiny mistake every time. I simplified and created a function in **R language**.

Here you go buddy!

```
numbers <- list(2,5,8,9,14,20) #List containing even odd numbers
en<-list()                     #Initiating even numbers’ list
on<-list()                     #Initiating odd numbers’ list

#Function creation

separate <- function(x){
for (i in x)
{

ifelse((i%%2)==0, en <- paste(append(en,i, length(en)+1), collapse = ","),
                  on <- paste(append(on,i, length(on)+1), collapse = ","))
}
message("Even numbers are : ", en)
message("Odd numbers are : ", on)
}

#Passing the function with argument

separate(numbers)
```

## Result!

Even numbers are : 2,8,14,20

Odd numbers are : 5,9